# How To Insert A Row After Each Group Based on the Row Immediately Above

Tags: excel, vba

Please see the sample table below which is similar to the actual table I'm working with in Excel - hopefully this is clear enough to illustrate my question. Using VBA, I want to add a new row based on each distinct cell in column 1 (i.e. for every change in value, insert a new row) and then populate that new row with the values in the row immediately above with a few modifications of that row (see columns 4, 10-13).

[image: Current and Desired Tables - JPEG]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code you posted got wiped out by the huge amount of whitespace at the bottom of the image. Please edit your question to include the code (working or not) you have achieved so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is updated code per your comments on my first answer. This code works on a pre-selected range and asks for your input for the column 4 value you would like to apply the code to.

```
Sub codeForMike()

Dim rowX As Integer
Dim rangeSize As Integer
Dim col4 As Integer

col4 = InputBox("Insert rows where column 4 =", "Enter Number:")

rangeSize = Selection.Rows.Count
Selection.Cells(1).Select

rowX = ActiveCell.Row
rangeSize = rowX + rangeSize

Do
If Cells(rowX, 4).Value <> col4 Then
    rowX = rowX + 1

Else
    Range(Cells(rowX + 1, 1), Cells(rowX + 1, 13)).Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Cells(rowX + 1, 1).Value = Cells(rowX, 1).Value
    Cells(rowX + 1, 2).Value = Cells(rowX, 2).Value
    Cells(rowX + 1, 3).Value = Cells(rowX, 3).Value
    Cells(rowX + 1, 6).Value = Cells(rowX, 6).Value
    Cells(rowX + 1, 7).Value = Cells(rowX, 7).Value
    Cells(rowX + 1, 8).Value = Cells(rowX, 8).Value
    Cells(rowX + 1, 9).Value = Cells(rowX, 9).Value
    Cells(rowX + 1, 10).Value = "0"
    Cells(rowX + 1, 11).Value = "0"
    Cells(rowX + 1, 12).Value = "0"
    Cells(rowX + 1, 13).Value = "0"

    rowX = rowX + 2
    rangeSize = rangeSize + 1
End If

Loop Until rowX = rangeSize



Range(Cells(rowX - 2, 1), Cells(rowX - 2, 13)).Copy
Cells(rowX - 1, 1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi SincereApathy - Thanks so much for this.  It worked perfectly.  Could you please let me know how i would need to edit your code if I wanted to leave column 4 of each new row blank (as this value will change)?  Again - thanks so much!

Comment: Also, is there a way to only run the code on only a selected part of an Excel worksheet?

Comment: If you want to leave column 4 blank just remove the following line: `Cells(rowX + 1, 4).Value = "86112"` If the value of column 4 can be defined by rules or if there is a data table to look up what the value should be we can modify the code to get the correct value.

If you only want to do this on part of the sheet just add "Or rowX = (desired stopping row)" to the Loop until line. For example `Loop Until Cells(rowX, 1).Value = "" Or rowX = 20`

Comment: Thanks again.  After re-thinking this a bit, would there be a way to insert a new row only if column 4 equals an identified value (e.g. insert new row if column 4 = 582).  Columns 6-9 would still need to be copies from above, and columns 10-13 would still be "0".

Comment: Thanks again.  After re-thinking this a bit, would there be a way to insert a new row only if column 4 equals an identified value (e.g. insert new row if column 4 = 582). Ideally I would need to be able to easily change the code to run it on different queries.  Columns 6-9 would still need to be copies from above, and columns 10-13 would still be "0".  Just to clarify on my second question, would there be a way to apply the code to only the part of the worksheet that I have highlighted beforehand?  Thank so much, again.

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect your suggestions in the previous comments.

Comment: This is great!  Thank you so much for all of your help with this - much appreciated!